# Why such huge difference in the array creation between c++ and Java

Tags: java, arrays, c++11

```
//C++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int tStart=clock();
    int a[10000000][2];
    for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

```
// Java Code
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int n=10000000;
        int [][]table=new int[n][2];
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(elapsedTime/1000.0);
    }
}
```

- C++ Runtime : 0.00s (I intentionally put the loop to initialise the array in case in java the array automatically gets initalized to 0.
- Java Runtime : 3.696s
- I was writing a code for a competitive website, that code requires a memo table of size M[10^7][24], I didnt know as i am very new to java that it will run out of memory, after getting TLE in most of the test cases i realised that the creation of table in taking huge time in java so, i reduced the jth value from 24 to 2 just for testing purposes, and found that it is taking 3.5 secs to just create the array while in c++ the time is 0.00s. So, what could be the reason behind this drastic difference.
- As I need to submit the code and the code is quite complex with runtime O(nlog(n))+O(n^2) and space O(log(n)), is there a way to create the array of dimensions M[10^7][24] in java?

Comment: With C++ as written the compiler might be changing the initialization to 0 to a single memset() call.  Try initializing to something like i*j in both.  Also, with C++ it does a single memory allocation for the entire table, because the size can't be changed.

Comment: Creating 10000000 objects takes time. You would get better results when you use `new int[2][n]`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471708/why-is-java-taking-long-time-initializing-two-dimensional-arrays-starting-with-t/43471809) about why the other approach works better for Java.